# An encoding scheme to shorten a string of numbers that is url safe

Tags: php, javascript, encoding

I have a string that looks like this (contains numbers, periods and dashes):

```
1372137673.276886940002-19690324617-19694854617-18953258947
```

Since I only have numbers, periods and dashes, I would like to use an url-safe (only numbers and letters) encoding scheme to shorten it. I also need to be able to reverse the encoded string to its original form.

I have had a look at base64, but it increases the size of the string by a fair bit, which is not what I want.

I plan to have this implemented in PHP and Javascript.

Are there any existing schemes that can do this? My main motivation is to make the above string shorter and the result should be URL safe.

Comment: you can try urlencode() and for decoding urldecode()

Comment: You have 12 symbols to encode (10 numbers, dash and dot) and at least 36 available symbols (24 letters, 10 numbers, dash and underscore). **Did you try** with a simple map (like base64 does)?

Comment: if you are okay with a string like this `d2rdbt.hfinz2tv-8y84nrx-8y93j9s-8fhkua4` then i think can help. because the code is a bit large

Comment: @bystwn22: That's certainly much better than the original string! Would love to see what you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the numbers into their binary form, then Base64 encode *that*.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in javascript also, you need the help of http://phpjs.org/ :)
i think all php functions i used in this script is available there, like [`bcomp`](http://phpjs.org/functions/bccomp/)
You can tweak this code to get an even smaller string, bit busy now, if i got time, sure i will update this answer :)

```
<?php
  /**
   * This function will encode a larger number to small string
  **/
  function encode( $int = null ) {
    $chars  = 'kwn7uh2qifbj8te9vp64zxcmayrg50ds31';
    $uid    = '';
    while( bccomp( $int, 0, 0) != 0 ) {
      $rem  = bcmod( $int, 34 );
      $int  = bcdiv( bcsub( $int, $rem, 0 ), 34, 0 );
      $uid  = $chars[$rem].$uid;
    }
    return $uid;
  }
  /**
   * This function will decode a string encoded with above function to its original state
  **/
  function decode( $uid = null ) {
    $chars  = 'kwn7uh2qifbj8te9vp64zxcmayrg50ds31';
    $id   = '';
    $len  = strlen( $uid );
    for( $i = $len - 1; $i >= 0; $i-- ) {
      $value  = strpos( $chars, $uid[$i] );
      $id     = bcadd( $id, bcmul( $value, bcpow( 34, ( $len - $i - 1 ) ) ) );
    }
    return $id;
  }
  /**
   * Below function is only for your needs
  **/
  function int_to_str( $str = null, $decode = false ) {
    //$len  = array(); // reserved for further updates :)
    $numbers1 = explode( "-", $str );
    foreach( $numbers1 as &$num1 ) {
      $func = ( $decode ) ? "decode" : "encode";
      $num1 = implode( ".", array_map( $func, explode( ".", $num1 ) ) );
    }
    $numbers1 = implode( "-", $numbers1 );
    return $numbers1;
  }

  // Encode your numbers to short strings
  $str  = int_to_str( "1372137673.276886940002-19690324617-19694854617-18953258947" );
  // Decode your encoded string to its original state
  $int  = int_to_str( $str, true );

  echo $str."<br />";
  echo $int;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable attempt would be:

- break down the string into tokens separated by dashes and dots
- convert each token to a higher base (36 is a base which you can convert to and from easily from both JS and PHP)
- join the tokens back together -- both dashes and dots are valid in a URL

However, the "have to do this in JS also" requirement seems a bit suspect -- why does your client-side code have to extract information from URLs which are ultimately under the server's authority? In general URLs should be opaque and when that's not true alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it was fun to do... it encodes the string on a custom base 64 keeping the separators intact:

```
function encode_token($digit) {
    if ($digit < 10)
        return (string) $digit;
    if ($digit < 36)
        return chr(ord('A') + ($digit - 10));
    if ($digit < 62)
        return chr(ord('a') + ($digit - 36));
    if ($digit == 62) return ',';
    return '+';
}

function encode_value($value) {
    if (in_array($value, array('.', '-'))) return $value;
    $int = (int) $value;

    $encoded = '';
    while($int) {
        $encoded .= encode_token($int & 0x3F);
        $int >>= 6;
    }
    return $encoded;
}

function encode($string) {
    $values = preg_split(',([\.-]),', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $encoded = '';
    foreach($values as $value)
        $encoded .= encode_value($value);
    return $encoded;
}

function decode_token($token) {
    if ($token <= '9') return (int) $token;
    if ($token <= 'Z') return 10 + ord($token) - ord('A');
    if ($token <= 'z') return 36 + ord($token) - ord('a');
    if ($token == ',') return 62;
    return 63;
}

function decode_value($value) {
    if (in_array($value, array('.', '-'))) return $value;

    $decoded = 0;
    for($i = strlen($value) - 1;$i >= 0;$i--) {
        $decoded <<= 6;
        $decoded |= decode_token($value[$i]);
    }
    return $decoded;
}

function decode($string) {
    $values = preg_split(',([\.-]),', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $decoded = '';
    foreach($values as $value)
        $decoded .= decode_value($value);
    return $decoded;
}

$string = '1372137673.276886940002-19690324617-19694854617-18953258947';
echo $string . PHP_EOL;
$encoded = encode($string);
echo $encoded . PHP_EOL;
$decoded = decode($encoded);
echo $decoded . PHP_EOL;
```